# SQL Server query to get attendance in one month

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I have a row master data like this:

```
EmpNo   DeptName  DateIn        TimeIn
---------------------------------------
001    HR        2018-10-04    08:10:00
001    HR        2018-10-05    08:11:00
001    HR        2018-10-08    07:00:00
002    HR        2018-10-04    08:15:00    
002    HR        2018-10-05    08:12:00
002    HR        2018-10-08    08:10:00
003    HR        2018-10-04    08:30:00
```

Could you please help me to find a best query to result like this:

```
    EmpNo   DeptName  DateIn        TimeIn
    001    HR        2018-10-04    08:10:00
    001    HR        2018-10-05    08:11:00
    001    HR        2018-10-06    n/a
    001    HR        2018-10-07    n/a
    001    HR        2018-10-08    07:00:00
    002    HR        2018-10-04    08:15:00    
    002    HR        2018-10-05    08:12:00
    002    HR        2018-10-06    n/a
    002    HR        2018-10-07    n/a
    002    HR        2018-10-08    08:10:00
    003    HR        2018-10-04    08:30:00
    003    HR        2018-10-05    --sickleave--
    003    HR        2018-10-06    n/a
    003    HR        2018-10-07    n/a
```

My query so far:

```
DECLARE @tbltgl TABLE (tgl DATE)
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @m VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @y VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @DeptName VARCHAR(100)

SET @m = '10';
SET @y = '2018';
SET @DeptName = 'HR'
SET @StartDate = @y + '-' + @m + '-01';
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(d, 30, @StartDate)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tbltgl
        SELECT @StartDate

    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
END

SELECT 
    b.BADGENUMBER AS NIK,
    b.NAME, 
    b.DEPTNAME,
    b.TITLE,
    a.tgl AS 'DATE',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.StartDateTime, 108) AS 'TIME IN'
FROM  
    @tbltgl a
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
     FROM VW_ATT_20181205b_DM b
     WHERE b.DEPTNAME = @DeptName
       AND MONTH(b.StartDateTime) = @m
       AND YEAR(b.StartDateTime) = @y) b ON a.tgl = b.TGL
ORDER BY 
    b.BADGENUMBER,
    CAST(a.TGL AS DATE)
```

Comment: You probably want to CROSS JOIN your date table with a list of DISTINCT employee numbers THEN use a left join on date/empno. Also guessing there's a leave table somewhere that you should also join. As a side note, creating a fixed calendar table is quite easy and saves you having to recreate it each time you want to do something like this.

Comment: There are better ways to build a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). A physical table is generally a better approach since it has so many and frequent uses but you can to it dynamically as well. That should be your first change. The while loop approach is very inefficient - which you will notice with a sufficiently large range or workload.

Comment: Hi SMor, thanks for your suggest. 
But, the problem is, i only have the read only access for the database's, because its not mine.
I'll tell to the dba to suggest this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the calendar table link, here is one way to do things. Notice the cross join (using the explicit "cross join" syntax) between the calendar and the list of "entities". This is how you generate rows for all dates for all entities. It isn't clear what your source data represents. Is the department name part of the "entry" information or is it an attribute of the employee. If the latter, the code could be simplified a bit. If you have a table of employees, then you don't need that cte and you can cross join the calendar with your employee table directly.

And one more comment. No one but you knows where "--sickleave--" comes from. I ignored this

```
set nocount on;
use tempdb;
go

declare @src table (empno smallint, deptname varchar(5), datein date, timein time(0)); 
insert @src (empno, deptname, datein, timein) 
values (1, 'HR', '2018-10-04', '08:10:00'), 
(1, 'HR', '2018-10-05', '08:11:00'), 
(1, 'HR', '2018-10-08', '07:00:00'), 
(2, 'HR', '2018-10-04', '08:15:00'),
(2, 'HR', '2018-10-05', '08:12:00'), 
(2, 'HR', '2018-10-08', '08:10:00'), 
(3, 'HR', '2018-10-04', '08:30:00');
select * from @src;


declare @StartDate date; 
declare @CutoffDate date; 
set @StartDate = '20181101';
--alternatively, use the current month when script runs
--set @start = getdate();
--set @start = dateadd(day, 1 - day(@start), @start);
set @CutoffDate = dateadd(day, 1, EOMONTH(@StartDate));
select @StartDate, @CutoffDate; 
-- To keep things simple, use your date range to match "desired output"
set @StartDate = '20181004';
set @CutoffDate = '20181008';
select @StartDate, @CutoffDate; 

-- see what the cte calendar generates
-- from: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/
with calendar as (
SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
) 
select * from calendar order by d; 

with calendar as (
SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    -- on my system this would support > 5 million days
    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
), 
emplist as (
select distinct empno, deptname from @src
)
select calendar.d, emplist.empno, emplist.deptname, 
    src.timein, 
    isnull(convert(char(8), src.timein, 108), 'n/a') as ftimein 
from calendar cross join emplist 
left join @src as src 
on emplist.empno = src.empno and emplist.deptname = src.deptname 
and calendar.d = src.datein
order by emplist.empno, emplist.deptname, calendar.d;
```

For future reference, this approach (including a complete or at least as complete as you can make it) is how to post an effective sql question. That provides others a platform on which to experiment and to build a working solution. It is best to include constraints (and indexes if performance is a consideration) - I did not because that is work you should do. I would also put a little more effort into formatting - but again, this is a quick, short demo and not production-ready code.

Notice also the commenting. When you "borrow" code from somewhere it is always a good idea to provide a link to the source. Since links can grow stale, you might want to save a copy of the webpage just in case. Attribution is good. Providing that link will let others better understand what you are doing.

Comment: Hi SMor, appreciate your response.
i'll try it first.

Comment: Hi SMor, i did some little changes from your query above, then its work for me now. 
Great! 
Many thanks for you and this forum!

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd use / create a couple dimension tables; Dates and Employees (assuming you want employees with no data at all). At that point, put the start date and end date in variables. A recursive CTE would also do the trick for the dates. Here's an example with the CTE. If you have a date dimension, just remove the CTE and replace it with that. Just be sure to put a range on the date dimension within the join, or you'll get a whole lot of junk data.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE,
     @EndDate DATE;

SET @StartDate = ...;
SET @EndDate = ...;

WITH DATES AS (
    SELECT
        @StartDate AS DateId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DD,1,DateId) AS DateId
    FROM DATES
    WHERE DATEADD(DD,1,DateId) <= @EndDate
)

SELECT
     COALESCE(m.EmpNo,e.EmpNo) AS EmpNo,
     COALESCE(m.DeptName,e.DeptName) AS DeptName,
     COALESCE(m.DateIn,d.DateId) AS DateIn,
     COALESCE(m.TimeIn,'n/a') AS TimeIn
FROM VW_ATT_20181205b_DM AS m
FULL JOIN DATES AS d -- DateId is UNIQUE in the recursive CTE
     ON m.DateIn = d.DateId
FULL JOIN Employees AS e -- EmpNo is UNIQUE in this table assumption
     ON m.EmpNo = e.EmpNo;
```

You can also dumb down the data from Employees if needed. This is a very dumbed down version... obviously, so please forgive anything that may be off. Think of this as more of pseudocode to guide.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this where all dates of a month has been taken as month date.

```
--To get all the dates of a month
declare @month int, @year int
set @month = 10
set @year = 2018

SELECT * INTO #tblAllMonthDate FROM(
SELECT
Convert(Varchar(20),CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + Number,110) as MonthDate
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND
(CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) + Number )
<
DATEADD(mm,1,CAST(CAST(@year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME) )
)a

create table #temp (EmpNo varchar(20),
DeptName varchar(2),
DateIn varchar(20),
TimeIn varchar(20)
)
insert into #temp values ('001', 'HR', '10-04-2018', '08:10:00')
insert into #temp values ('001', 'HR', '10-05-2018', '08:11:00')
insert into #temp values ('001', 'HR', '10-08-2018', '07:00:00')
insert into #temp values ('002', 'HR', '10-04-2018', '08:15:00')   
insert into #temp values ('002', 'HR', '10-05-2018', '08:12:00')
insert into #temp values ('002', 'HR', '10-08-2018', '08:10:00')
insert into #temp values ('003', 'HR', '10-04-2018', '08:30:00')

select distinct #temp.* from #temp
union
select distinct #temp.EmpNo as EmpNo,'HR' as DeptName, monthdate, 'na/a'  from(
select #tblAllMonthDate.MonthDate, EmpNo,ISNULL(DeptName,'HR') as DeptName, isnull(DateIn,#tblAllMonthDate.MonthDate) as DateIn, Isnull(TimeIn,'n/a') TimeIn from #tblAllMonthDate
left join #temp on Convert(Varchar(20),Convert(Datetime,#temp.DateIn),112) = Convert(Varchar(20),Convert(Datetime,#tblAllMonthDate.MonthDate),112)
where DAY(MonthDate) <=8 and DAY(MonthDate) >= 4
)as a , #temp
where a.EmpNo is null

drop table #tblAllMonthDate
drop table #temp
```

Here #temp is the original table contains attendance data. First all data of original table has been taken and then union has been used to get all the date for absent empno.

The output of the program is as follows:

```
EmpNo   DeptName    DateIn      TimeIn
001     HR          10-04-2018  08:10:00
001     HR          10-05-2018  08:11:00
001     HR          10-06-2018  na/a
001     HR          10-07-2018  na/a
001     HR          10-08-2018  07:00:00
002     HR          10-04-2018  08:15:00
002     HR          10-05-2018  08:12:00
002     HR          10-06-2018  na/a
002     HR          10-07-2018  na/a
002     HR          10-08-2018  08:10:00
003     HR          10-04-2018  08:30:00
003     HR          10-06-2018  na/a
003     HR          10-07-2018  na/a
```

You need to only join leave table for sick leave. You can get this leave data with another union in existing table.

Answer (score -2):

try this query using sub query to get all dates in current range:

```
DECLARE @DeptName VARCHAR(100) = 'HR'
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = '20181001'
DECLARE @ToDate datetime= '20181030'

;WITH DateRange AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, cast(@FromDate as date), cast (@ToDate as date)) + 1) 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) as DateValue
  FROM sys.all_objects
),

DateRangeTable as 
(
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, DateRange.DateValue-1, @FromDate) as Date) as DateValue
    FROM DateRange
)

SELECT 
    b.BADGENUMBER AS NIK,
    b.NAME, 
    b.DEPTNAME,
    b.TITLE,
    a.DateValue AS 'DATE',
    MIN(CASE WHEN a.DateValue = b.DEPTNAME AND b.StartDateTime IN NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.StartDateTime, 108) ELSE 'n/a' END) AS 'TIME IN'
FROM DateRangeTable a,VW_ATT_20181205b_DM b
GROUP BY b.BADGENUMBER,
         b.Name,
         a.DateValue,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.StartDateTime, 108) ELSE 'n/a' END)
ORDER BY 
    b.BADGENUMBER,
    DateValue
```

Comment: Hhi @bat7, many thanks for your response.
But the result still same as mine.

Comment: you are right, i missed something, i now edit my answer, try it.

Comment: hi bat, the result still same.
but i'm still do the modify from query that you suggest.

Comment: No one should be using old-style joins (via the where clause). But this won't work since your group by clause does not include all the unaggregated columns. It would also be a big service to OP to explain you cross join. Code-only answers are discouraged because they don't teach.